# Return in eval function for Php

Tags: php

I need to pass a return $variable; within the eval function, which in turn is going to return a value for a function.

Here is an example:

```
function something()
{
    $sSomeVar = 'something';
    eval( 'return $sSomeVar = 3;'  );
}
```

The code above will return 3 for the eval, but the function will not return the value for the variable.

So does anyone know how to return a return within an eval?

Comment: Only wanted to note that eval is evil. Now you have been warned ;)

Comment: If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question - Rasmus Lerdorf

Comment: function evil($str){return eval($str);} //a handy wrapper

Comment: If you may explain, what is your **original** problem, maybe we will able to find a solution without using eval. @sigint: +1

Comment: The code with the the function cannot be changed. The eval is actually part of a plugin class that calls the php code and process the php code using an eval. So, I want to return the function (in the example I give its the function "something") using the eval. So the code in the function cannot change, only the string within the eval.

Comment: than, my friend, it cannot be done.

Comment: Ya, I figured. I just wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
function something() 
{
  $sSomeVar = 'something';
  return eval( 'return $sSomeVar = 3;' );
}
```

Comment: I cannot recode the the function. So that solution is not available.